# In R dataframe, how to change numeric variable in easy way

Tags: r, dataframe

In R dataframe, I want to change the numeric variables to opposite number (multiply -1 ) where category equal 'a' or 'b'.
Currently, the code is little longer, is the any other way for this ? Thanks!

```
test_data <- data.frame(category=c("a","b","x","a","b","c","d"),
           amount_local=c(10,30,52,5,67,5,20),
           amount_usd=c(1,3,5,7,8,3,4))

test_data$amount_local[test_data$category %in% c('a','b') ] <- test_data$amount_local[test_data$category %in% c('a','b') ]*-1

test_data$amount_usd[test_data$category %in% c('a','b') ] <- test_data$amount_usd[test_data$category %in% c('a','b') ]*-1
```

Additional Question: I have recived some many useful method for original question. Additional,  When we have two conditions variable as blow, the 'update code' can't work .   @Ronak Shah ,Could your help on this.Thanks!

```
test_data_new <- data.frame(
    category=c("a","b","x","a","b","c","d"), sub_category=c("a","b","x","a","b","c","d"), amount_local=c(10,30,52,5,67,5,20),
    amount_usd=c(1,3,5,7,8,3,4))
```

----- the begin of 'update code'

```
   ind_new <- test_data_new $category %in% c('a','b') & test_data_new $csub_ategory %in% c('a') 
    
    test_data_new [ind,c(-1,-2)] <- test_data_new [ind, c(-1,-2)] * -1
```

----- the end of 'update code'

Comment: There are some typos in your additional question. 1. No space should be there between dataframe name and column names. So not `test_data_new $category` but `test_data_new$category`. 2. You are using `csub_ategory` but your column name is `sub_category`. 3. You should use `ind_new` instead of `ind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
test_data %>% mutate(across(starts_with('amount'), ~ ifelse(category %in% c('a','b'), . * -1, .)))
  category amount_local amount_usd
1        a          -10         -1
2        b          -30         -3
3        x           52          5
4        a           -5         -7
5        b          -67         -8
6        c            5          3
7        d           20          4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can multiply multiple columns together. To avoid repeating the condition you can save it in a variable.

```
inds <- test_data$category %in% c('a','b')
test_data[inds, -1] <- test_data[inds, -1] * -1

#  category amount_local amount_usd
#1        a          -10         -1
#2        b          -30         -3
#3        x           52          5
#4        a           -5         -7
#5        b          -67         -8
#6        c            5          3
#7        d           20          4
```

Comment: if i add condition columnis,it could's work.  Could your help on this? Thanks !    
         test_data <- data.frame(category=c("a","b","x","a","b","c","d"),
                        sub_category=c("a","b","x","a","b","c","d"),
           amount_local=c(10,30,52,5,67,5,20),
           amount_usd=c(1,3,5,7,8,3,4))

ind <- test_data$category %in% c('a','b') & test_data$csub_ategory %in% c('a')

test_data[ind,c(-1,-2)] <- test_data[ind, c(-1,-2)] * -1

Comment: Sorry what is the question? What you have tried (in the comment above) works and is correct. @anderwyang

Comment: Could you help on my 'additional question ' (i edited my question and add more contend) .Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple columns at once if the conditions are the same.

```
test_data[test_data$category %in% c('a','b'), c('amount_local', 'amount_usd')] <- test_data[test_data$category %in% c('a','b'), c('amount_local', 'amount_usd')] * -1
```

Also plenty of `dplyr` solutions that should be pretty clear if you have a little read.